# How can I remove this bathtub drain?

Tags: drain, bathtub, removal

I have this bathtub that had a trip lever drain that kept getting stuck so the water would not drain unless you have a foot on the trip lever while you're showering (not ideal). I decided to replace it with a push down stopper. It was easy to take out the lever but the bath drain is nearly impossible. I tried everything, turning pliers into levers and giving it some torque. I went out to buy a drain remover but it just would not turn. I was wondering if anyone have any other ingenious ideas? It's not a cross hatch drain but just a horizontal bar that runs down the middle.

I never replaced a bath drain before so maybe I'm doing it all wrong so any advice/tips would be greatly appreciated.

here's a picture of it:
[image: the impossible drain]

Comment: With the chips in the tub, I presume you will replace the tub?

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy something to break up the rust fusion you have going on.  WD-40 makes a variety but there are many at your local DIY center.

I would then tap around the drain.  Then get a blunt/dull metal block or chisel and hold it against the inner straps and tap on those counter-clockwise.  The tapping (with a hammer or mallet) is probably the key to breaking up the rust bond.  You can't just start cracking it hard or you could snap one of the center straps or warp the outside.